# Can't get checkboxfield values to show

Tags: field, conditional, forloop, checkboxes

I'm trying to build a filter and for that I want my client to be able to select a few options, which I use as classes for in my filter.

I chose for a checkbox field and set it up in the backend. Now I'm trying to retrieve the data on the HTML side, but I can only retrieve ALL values, instead of only the selected ones.

This is how my HTML/twig markup looks like

```
{% for option in entry.offerMinimumPrice.options %} 
  {% if option.selected %}
    {{ option }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

With this code none of the values gets displayed in the front end. When I remove the conditional statement, all values get displayed (instead of only the selected ones).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The code you have should be working fine.  Are you sure you're looking at the correct entry and that entry actually has something checked in the `offerMinimumPrice` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used this code within an entry, so I had to use the tag of that entry (offer) instead of entry.

The code that works now is:

```
{% for option in offer.offerMinimumPrice.options %}
  {% if option.selected %}
    {{ option }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a comma-separated list of selected options, try this.

```
{% for option in offer.offerMinimumPrice.options|filter(v => v.selected) %}
    {{ option.label }}{% if loop.last==false %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`for` provides a [loop](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) object that provides many useful variables.

[filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) can be used to filter down items in a list or map using an arrow function. Given that `selected` is a boolean, you just need to return the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
{% for option in entry.offerMinimumPrice %} 
    {{ option }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Unfortunately, that doesn't return any values as well.